Getit in flutter throwing unexpected error
I am getting this error "GetIt: The compiler could not infer the type. You have to provide a type and optionally a name. Did you accidentally do var sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of var sl=GetIt.instance;
'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart':
Failed assertion: line 404 pos 7: 'type != null || const Object() is! T'
"
I don't know why this error is showing
i tried to register the AccountsBloc again but still the same problem,the other Blocs are working fine. please help me.
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cashbook/fetures/accounts/data/datasorces/accounts_remote_datasource.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/accounts/data/repositries/accounts_repositry_implementation.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/accounts/domain/repositries/accounts_repositry.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/accounts/domain/usecases/create_account.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/accounts/domain/usecases/delete_account.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/accounts/domain/usecases/get_all_accounts.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/accounts/domain/usecases/update_account.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/accounts/presentation/bloc/accounts_bloc.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/data/datasorces/payment_entry_remote_datasorse.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/data/datasorces/purchase_entry_remote_datasorce.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/data/datasorces/sales_entry_remote_datasorce.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/data/repositries/payment_entry_repository_implementation.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/data/repositries/purchase_entry_repository_implementation.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/data/repositries/sales_entry_repository_implementation.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/repositries/payment_entry_repository.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/repositries/sales_entry_repository.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/payment_entry_usecases/create_payment_entry_usecase.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/payment_entry_usecases/delete_all_payment_entry.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/payment_entry_usecases/delete_payment_entry_usecase.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/payment_entry_usecases/get_account_payment_entry_usecase.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/payment_entry_usecases/get_all_payment_entry_usecase.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/payment_entry_usecases/update_payment_entry_usecase.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/purchase_entry_usecases/create_purchase_entry.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/purchase_entry_usecases/delete_purchase_entry.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/purchase_entry_usecases/get_account_purchase_entry.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/purchase_entry_usecases/get_all_purchase_entry.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/purchase_entry_usecases/get_purchase_entry_by_id.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/purchase_entry_usecases/update_purchase_entry.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/sales_entry_usecases/create_sales_entry.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/sales_entry_usecases/delete_all_sales_entries.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/sales_entry_usecases/delete_sales_entry.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/sales_entry_usecases/get_account_sales_entries.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/sales_entry_usecases/get_all_sales_entry.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/sales_entry_usecases/get_sales_entry_by_id.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/domain/use_cases/sales_entry_usecases/update_sales_entry.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/presentation/bloc/payment_entry_bloc.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/presentation/bloc/purchase_entry_bloc.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/entries/presentation/bloc/sales_entry_bloc.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sqflite;
import 'package:sqflite_common_ffi/sqflite_ffi.dart';

GetIt serviceLocator = GetIt.instance;

Future<sqflite.Database> initialiseDatabase() async {
  String db2Path;
  sqflite.DatabaseFactory factory;
  sqfliteFfiInit();
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    db2Path = await sqflite.getDatabasesPath();
    factory = databaseFactory;
  } else {
    db2Path = await databaseFactoryFfi.getDatabasesPath();

    factory = databaseFactoryFfi;
  }
  final db = openDB(factory, db2Path);
  return db;
}

Future<sqflite.Database> openDB(
    sqflite.DatabaseFactory factory, String db2Path) {
  return factory.openDatabase(
    join(db2Path, "main_database.db"),
    options: OpenDatabaseOptions(
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (db, version) async {
        await db.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON");
      },
      onConfigure: (db) async {
        await db.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts_table(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
 )
""");

        await db.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS purchase_entries_table(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  accountName TEXT NOT NULL,
  perticularName TEXT NOT NULL,
  nweight INTEGER NOT NULL,
  date INTEGER NOT NULL,
  discription TEXT NOT NULL,
  purchasingRate INTEGER NOT NULL,
  taxRate INTEGER NOT NULL,
  taxAmount INTEGER NOT NULL,
  amountDr INTEGER NOT NULL,
  amountCr INTEGER NOT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (accountName) REFERENCES accounts_table(name) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 )
""");
        await db.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sales_entries_table(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  accountName TEXT NOT NULL,
  perticularName TEXT NOT NULL,
  date INTEGER NOT NULL,
  taxRate INTEGER NOT NULL,
  nweight INTEGER NOT NULL,
  taxAmount INTEGER NOT NULL,
  discription TEXT NOT NULL,
  sellingRate INTEGER NOT NULL,
  amountDr INTEGER NOT NULL,
  amountCr INTEGER NOT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (accountName) REFERENCES accounts_table(name) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 )
""");
        await db.execute("""

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payment_entries_table(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  accountName TEXT NOT NULL,
  date INTEGER NOT NULL,
  discription TEXT NOT NULL,
  amountDr INTEGER NOT NULL,
  amountCr INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (accountName) REFERENCES accounts_table(accountName) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 )
""");
      },
    ),
  );
}

Future<void> initDependencies() async {
  _initialiseAccounts();
  _initialiseSalesEntries();
  _initialisePurchaseEntries();
  _initialisePaymentEntries();
  final Database db = await initialiseDatabase();
  serviceLocator.registerSingleton(db);
}

void _initialiseAccounts() {
  serviceLocator.registerFactory<AccountsRemoteDatasource>(
    () => AccountsRemoteDatasourceImplementation(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory<AccountsRepository>(
    () => AccountsRepositoryImplementation(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );
  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => CreateAccount(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );
  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => GetAllAccounts(
      accountsRepository: serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => UpdateAccount(
      accountRepository: serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => DeleteAccount(
      accountRepository: serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

   serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton<AccountsBloc>(
    () => AccountsBloc(
      createAccount: serviceLocator(),
      getAllAccounts: serviceLocator(),
      updateAccount: serviceLocator(),
      deleteAccount: serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

 }

void _initialiseSalesEntries() {
  print("hellooooo");
  serviceLocator.registerFactory<SalesRemoteDatasorce>(
    () => SalesRemoteDatasorceImplementation(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );
  serviceLocator.registerFactory<SalesEntryRepository>(
    () => SalesEntryImplementation(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => CreateSalesEntry(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => GellAllSalesEntries(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => GetAccountSalesEntries(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => UpdateSalesEntry(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => DeleteSalesEntry(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => DeleteAllSalesEntries(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => GetSalesEntryById(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );
  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton(
    () => SalesEntryBloc(
      createSalesEntry: serviceLocator(),
      gellAllSalesEntries: serviceLocator(),
      getAccountSalesEntries: serviceLocator(),
      updateSalesEntry: serviceLocator(),
      deleteSalesEntry: serviceLocator(),
      deleteAllSalesEntries: serviceLocator(),
      getSalesEntryById: serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );
}

void _initialisePurchaseEntries() {
  serviceLocator.registerFactory<PurchaseEntryRemoteDataSource>(
    () => PurchaseEntryRemoteDataSourceImplementation(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );
  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => PurchaseEntryRepositoryImplementation(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => GetAllPurchaseEntries(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => GetPurchaseEntryById(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => CreatePurchaseEntry(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => UpdatePurchaseEntry(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => DeletePurchaseEntry(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => GetAccountPurchaseEntry(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton(
    () => PurchaseEntryBloc(
      getAllPurchaseEntries: serviceLocator(),
      getPurchaseEntryById: serviceLocator(),
      createPurchaseEntry: serviceLocator(),
      updatePurchaseEntry: serviceLocator(),
      deletePurchaseEntry: serviceLocator(),
      getAccountPurchaseEntry: serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );
}

void _initialisePaymentEntries() {
  serviceLocator.registerFactory<PaymentEntryRemoteDataSource>(
    () => PaymentEntryRemoteDatasorseImplementation(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );
  serviceLocator.registerFactory<PaymentEntryRepository>(
    () => PaymentEntryRepositoryImplementation(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => GetAllPaymentEntryUsecase(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => DeleteAllPaymentEntryUseCase(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => CreatePaymentEntryUsecase(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => UpdatePaymentEntryUsecase(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => GetAccountPaymentEntryUsecase(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerFactory(
    () => DeletePaymentEntryUsecase(
      serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );

  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton(() => PaymentEntryBloc(
        getAllPaymentEntryUsecase: serviceLocator(),
        deleteAllPaymentEntryUsecase: serviceLocator(),
        createPaymentEntryUsecase: serviceLocator(),
        updatePaymentEntryUsecase: serviceLocator(),
        getAccountPaymentEntryUsecase: serviceLocator(),
        deletePaymentEntryUsecase: serviceLocator(),
      ));
}

this is the code of the page in which i am calling the bloc event
import 'package:cashbook/core/loading_indicator.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/core/utils/show_snackbar.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/accounts/presentation/bloc/accounts_bloc.dart';
import 'package:cashbook/fetures/accounts/presentation/pages/account_details.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class AccountsListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AccountsListPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<AccountsListPage> createState() => _AccountsListPageState();
}

class _AccountsListPageState extends State<AccountsListPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    context.read<AccountsBloc>().add(AccountsGet());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Accounts"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        title: const Text("Create new account"),
                        content: TextField(
                          canRequestFocus: true,
                          autofocus: true,
                          decoration:
                              const InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter name "),
                          onSubmitted: (value) {
                            context
                                .read<AccountsBloc>()
                                .add(AccountsCreateEvent(name: value.trim()));
                            context.read<AccountsBloc>().add(AccountsGet());
                          },
                          onChanged: (value) {},
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add))
        ],
      ),
      body: BlocConsumer<AccountsBloc, AccountsState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is AccountsGetSuccess) {
            showSnackBar(context, const Text("got the accounts"));
          }
          if (state is AccountsFailure) {
            showSnackBar(context, const Text("failed to get the accounts"));
          }
          if (state is AccountsCreateSuccess) {
            showSnackBar(context, const Text("Account created successfully"));
          }
          if (state is AccountsDeleteSuccess) {
            showSnackBar(context, const Text("Account deleted successfully"));
            context.read<AccountsBloc>().add(AccountsGet());
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is AccountsLoading) {
            return const LoadingIndicator();
          }
          if (state is AccountsGetSuccess) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: state.accounts.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(state.accounts[index].name),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return AccountDetails(
                            id: state.accounts[index].id!,
                            name: state.accounts[index].name);
                      }));
                    },
                  );
                });
          }
          return const SizedBox();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}



You've already registered before your Bloc class:
Here code which works:
serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton(
() => SalesEntryBloc(....

You should probably try registering not like registerLazySingleton<AccountsBloc> but try without <...>:
  serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton(
() => AccountsBloc(
   ...
),


it did not work

Show me all file code, please. You can upload it on GitHub Gist or something like that. I will try to help you.
Take care about typo in code, please :) I suppose there is chance of typo in code.
